# How can I get 'language code' in main function?

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I get language code in main function?
I want to language code for push notification for localization?

Comment: What's your objection to including MaterialApp in your app? (If I read that correctly.)

Comment: No, I want to get language code in main function, I know how to get language code in material app, but I don't know how to get before material app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.window.locales;
```

It helped me.